# Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined React Native and Parse

Tags: react-native, parse-platform

I've started learning React Native with Redux and I'm building a simple login with Google and Facebook login which I want to sent to a Parse backend on AWS.

I have the following Facebook Button Component:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import { createUser } from '../actions';

class FacebookButton extends Component {

  facebookButtonPressed(){
      this.props.createUser("dummyemail@gmail.com","12345");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
          onPress={this.facebookButtonPressed.bind(this)}
          title="Sign In with Facebook"
          color="#000000"
      />
    );
  }

}

export default connect(null,{ createUser })(FacebookButton);
```

I haven't done any Facebook integration yet, I just want to see if I can create a parse user. This is the action I'm using:

```
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';

export const createUser = (email, name) => {
    return (dispatch) => {

      var user = new Parse.User();
      user.set("username", "my name");
      user.set("password", "my pass");
      user.set("name",name);
      user.set("email", email);

      // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
      user.set("phone", "415-392-0202");

      user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
          // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
          console.log("User created");
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
          // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });


    }
};
```

When I run the debugger in the browser, I'm able to see that the `createUser` is called and when we call `user.signUp` I get the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'reactNative.AsyncStorage.getItem')
```

When I read the Parse Javascript docs and try the following:

```
//Get your favorite AsyncStorage handler with import (ES6) or require
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'; 

//Before using the SDK...
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
```

I call the `Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);` in the code below.

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

export default class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      Parse.initialize("MY KEY");
      Parse.serverURL = 'MY URL';
      Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Login />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error of `reactNative2.default.setAsyncStorage is not a function`. Frankly I tried `Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);` in hopes of this fixing the AsyncStorage issue mentioned above.

So any ideas as to why I get the funny AsyncStorage error message when trying to create a Parse user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving an answer here in case someone else stumbles across any other issues. The problem was the version of `Parse` I was using. I was using Parse version `1.6.14`. Steps to fix:

1. Open the `package.json` file and update your Parse version to any version above `1.11`, for me `1.11.1` worked.
2. In the terminal: `npm install`

this should fix the issues mentioned above, bear in mind that you have to implement:

```
//Get your favorite AsyncStorage handler with import (ES6) or require
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'; 

//Before using the SDK...
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);
```

as per documentation.